# CSS is not working for some part, but works for its child

Tags: css, sass

I've given up with this one, and I don't know where I did wrong.

this is the SCSS

```
div#home {
    background-image: url(/assets/bg/home.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    .limiter {
        margin-top: $NAVBAR_BODY_START;
    }
}
```

This is the resulting CSS. Take note that `div#home` are compiled succesfully, along with `.limiter` class below.

[image: Resulting CSS]

And this is what Chrome rendered. I've tested with Edge, and it was also failed.

[image: Chrome Element debug screen]

Interesting part is that `.limiter` class inside `div#home` works. But not `div#home` where it is nested.

[image: Limiter works]

Any idea where it goes wrong?

Comment: under `div#content` there seem to be 2 stray styles that don't seem to belong anywhere. `line-height` and `font-size` . It may indicate a syntax issue with the SCSS

Comment: Ah.. thank you for spotting that.. it should be under `p`. Seems I unknowingly deleted something. My bad.

Comment: @apokryfos can you put it as answer so I can close this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under `div#content` there seem to be 2 stray styles that don't seem to belong anywhere.

```
/* ... */   
line-height: 1.5em; 
font-size: 2vmin;
/* ... */
```

This may indicate a syntax issue with the SCSS.

Answer (score 1):

I think background-image: url(/assets/bg/home.jpg); should be background-image: url("/assets/bg/home.jpg"). Can you give it a try?